# Delta Credit Spread risk weights under FRTB SA

Tags: frtb

Is there any discussion on risk weights for non-securitization credit spread sensitivities under FRTB SA? They seem quite large, and would like to understand why.

I could only find references about the [Danish covered bond market](https://www.scanrate.dk/blog/archive/will-frtb-increase-required-capital-for-floating-rate-notes/), where banks finance mortgage bonds with these bonds.